# What does CMP dword ptr [EBP + local_c],0xdeadbeef mean?

Tags: assembly, x86

Can somebody please explain what does

```
CMP        dword ptr [EBP + local_c], 0xdeadbeef
```

means. As far as I understand it compare the `EBP+local_c` location value with 0xdeadbeef, but I am not sure if that is true.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 0xdeadbeef is a dummy term used in the early days of labeling values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EBP + local_c] is an address, in an indirect addressing mode.  EBP plus some offset.  For this assembly language (defined by the assembler not the target) to indicate what size this indirect address based instruction should operate on has dword ptr meaning the first operand is a 32 bit value at the address indicated.  The second operand is an immediate value, a constant 0xdeadbeef.

This instruction is saying read the 32 bit value from address EBP + local_c and do a CMP instruction with the value 0xdeadbeef.   CMP means do a subtract operation, save the flags but do not save the result.  So the zero flag and others will be modified based on the subtract between these two operands.

Instructions that follow will ideally make decisions based on the flags computed during this instruction.

Answer (score 4):

`EBP + local_c` is considered as memory address here, pointing to a `dword` value. The instruction

```
CMP  dword ptr [EBP + local_c], 0xdeadbeef
```

therefore compares the value at this memory position with `0xdeadbeef`.